# Sql Server - Alternative of doing a RTRIM/LTRIM in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, trim

I hava a column name which is a varchar

I want to filter all results where name is an empty string...

```
 select name 
 from tblNames
 where name <> ''
```

What I want to do is:

```
 select name 
 from tblNames
 where Ltrim(RTrim(name)) <> ''
```

I want to apply a trim on name in the where clause but I have read a few articles mentioning the performance issue of functions inside the where clause

I want a solution to this without hurting performance

Comment: Just to be clear - have you got entries that are just spaces i.e. more than just an empty string?

Comment: It can empty strings as well as nulls and spaces as well

Comment: Well there's are the following options in terms of content: 1. nulls 2. Empty strings 3. Spaces only 4. Data with optional spaces.  If you're trying to avoid just 1 and 2 you can do `where name <> '' and name is not null` - in some setups, that would also ignore 3.  But if you want to explicitly avoid 3 by removing spaces then you probably need a function.  `where name <> ''` does ignore nulls on certain config as well so could be sufficient

Comment: And doesn't that `where name <> ''` work?

Comment: If I have spaces saved then it moght not.

Comment: @abbas: You didn't check then? By default, a string consisting of spaces matches an empty string in SQL Server, i.e. `'   ' = ''`.

Comment: @Andriy: Thnx, that was my impression. I don't know what settigns may affect this (default) behaviour though.

Comment: @Andriy...Thanks..I just cheke and you are right.

Comment: @ypercube: I'm not sure either, to be honest. As far as I can remember, standard behaviour when comparing strings with `=`, `<>` etc. is to ignore trailing spaces. And since Transact-SQL allows one to change certain aspects of standard behaviour, I thought there might be some `SET xyz ON/OFF` instruction regarding the trailing spaces too. If I ever encountered such a thing, I just can't remember now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Standard behaviour in SQL-Server is that

```
'      ' = ''
```

is `TRUE`, because trailing spaces are ignored. From [MSDN support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626):

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2, , General rules #3) on how to compare strings with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of `WHERE` and `HAVING` clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings **`'abc'`** and **`'abc '`** to be **equivalent** for most comparison operations.
>
> The only exception to this rule is the `LIKE` predicate. ...

So, your condition `WHERE name <> ''` should work fine, and not include any strings where there are only spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a constraint that only trimmed data goes in the field.

You could make an index on `LTRIM(RTRIM(name))`. SQL Might be smart enough to use it.

You could make a calculated field that is `LTRIM(RTRIM(name))`, index that field, and then use that field in your query.

Answer (score 3):

While

> `'abc' = 'abc       '`

(with spaces after the string on the right hand side of the equasion) is `TRUE`

> `'abc' = '     abc'`

(with spaces before the string on the right hand side of the equasion) is `FALSE`.

Therefore what is automatically ignored is the trailing spaces only (works like `RTRIM` but not like `LTRIM`).